# Is wild char supported in elevate.xml in Solr QueryElevationComponent?

Tags: solr, lucene, solr-boost

I need to configure my solr engine is such way that I can elevate and skip some documents always, so I was referring to [this document](https://wiki.apache.org/solr/QueryElevationComponent), however not sure whether this is supported or not. e.g. Can we specify the "text" attribute of  element like following sample elevate.xml?

```
<elevate>

   <query text="*:*">
     <doc id="A" />
     <doc id="B" />
   </query>

   <query text="partialQueryText*">
     <doc id="A" />
     <doc id="B" exclude="true" />
   </query>

</elevate>
```

Any idea?

Answer (score -2):

No, you cannot do that, you can only use a fixed query like foo bar